# Table cell padding woes with Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, html-table, padding

I am having a lot of trouble with table cell paddings in Chrome. It seems that if a table cell does not contain pure text, then no padding is applied at all.

My markup:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th class="account-picture"></th>
            <th class="account-name">Name</th>
            <th class="account-email">Email</th>
            <th class="account-last">Last Sign in</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <fieldset>
                   <ul>        
                       <li><input type="checkbox" id="enabled" name="test[]" value="enabled"></li>
                   </ul>    
                </fieldset>
            </td>

            <td class="account-picture">
                   <div class="online">
                      <img src="http://www.genengnews.com/app_themes/genconnect/images/default_profile.jpg">                           </div>
            </td>
            <td class="account-name">test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</td>
            <td class="account-email">test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</td>
            <td class="account-last">15 April 2012 10:19 AM</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

The CSS:

```
img{ 
    height: 42px;
    width: 42px;
}

td, th{      
    padding: 0 12px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.account-picture{
    width: 40px;

}

.account-name{
    min-width: 100px;
}

.account-email{
    min-width: 120px;
}

.account-last{
    min-width: 140px;
}

table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
 }

td, th{      
   word-wrap: break-word;
   padding: 0 12px;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

td:first-child, th:first-child{
  width: 14px;
}
```

And the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5mPFk/1/

And this is what it renders as in firefox 11:
[image]

Chrome: 18 (latest):
[image]

IE9:
[image]

As can be seen, IE and FF works properly, but not with chrome. Why is this happening and what are possible solutiosn for this?

Comment: Maybe it'll help to close the your `input` element: `<input ... />`, although I find it kind of strange if Chrome wouldn't handle that gracefully... (same goes for your `img` element btw)

Comment: Still seeing the same issue with a closed input element. Although I don't think it's necessary to close the input tag if using the HTML5 doctype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed `table-layout: fixed` and it seems to work.

If `table-layout: fixed` is to be used, then `width` instead of `min-width` should be use to define column widths.

Not sure why only Chrome was playing up, but perhaps it has a better standards implementation.