# browser is auto-resizing grid layout

Tags: html, css

I cant seem to figure out why ( only chrome ) auto resizes my grid layout in my store

[image]

it only does it on 2 pages throught the whole store -

```
  http://www.towingpartsoutlet.com/chain-assemblies-grade-80-chain-assemblies-3-8-chain-assemblies-g80.html
  http://www.towingpartsoutlet.com/chain-assemblies-grade-70-chain-assemblies-5-16-grade-70-v-chains.html
```

there are no browser specific rules in the css...

Im very confused. Can anyone Please help.

Comment: Your text is rendering at a different size on each element.  Since your boxes are only set to have a padding to show width, the text is dictating the size of the box.  You may say the width is 33%, but Chrome adds the padding to the 33% and makes it much larger

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158893/table-cell-padding-woes-with-chrome and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605367/chrome-vs-ff-ie-opera-in-calculating-table-cell-width-table-layoutfixed.  I suggest getting rid of the padding and make a div inside of the table cell that sits center at a fixed size

Comment: Looks to me like an `overflow` issue. Try setting `overflow:hidden;` to the main wrap (the one with the yellow gradient background).

Comment: @ntgCleaner I've never experienced what you mention...

Comment: i do not thing it is a overflow issue - i think it is the padding .. because when i remove, it fixes the problem.

Comment: Might not be overflow actually...looking now. It's weird.

Comment: Padding where exactly?

Comment: Check my updated answer. Think I solved it. :D If it works, please don't forget to ACCEPT it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `line 34` of your css file, `css-element.css`. Replace everything with this. Should work better than what you had before (even on the other browsers, the `table` was overlapping a bit). :D

```
tr, td {
    margin: 0 2px 2px 0;
    display: inline-table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

***Then add this CSS as well (before the tr/td code):***

```
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: your css worked. Thank you very much.... how does this keep chrome from adding the padding ?

Comment: The padding wasn't really the issue, per say. But I used `box-sizing:border-box` to ensure the padding wasn't ADDING to the element width, instead the padding was applied within the 33% `td` width. More info on `box-sizing` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing